# YII Framework Publishing Issue

Tags: php, yii, publish

I have developed one website in YII framework. I have uploaded my all the files via FTP, and I also have added database. (I have Windows based hosting - Plesk Cpenal)

I am not able to run my website, After some re-search, I came to know that, I need to Publish the website first and then I need to run it. It shows the following error: http://ss.aemonindia.com/admin/backend/web/

So is this the right suggestion? Or any other issue would be there. And if yes, Then how to publish this website?

Here is my index.php code :

```html
<?php
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/bootstrap.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../config/bootstrap.php');

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main-local.php')
);

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

Comment: what version of PHP run on your server? and what's on index.php line 10?

Answer (score 0):

In Yii2 before use site you must usually "init" it (by running `yii init` or `php yii init` depends on your environment).

But right now you have error in "index.php" file syntax on line 10. Fix it or show the file content here to help you.